# Metadata not showing up in opensea testnet

Tags: solidity, nft, erc-721, opensea, meta-data

I have encountered a very annoying problem for me. OpenSea and LooksRare (testnets) don't want to display my nft metadata. I'll attach pictures below.

Contract constructor:
[image]

Deploy script:
[image]

Metadata:
[image]

I minted 2 tokens => 2 metadata files. Please help me figure it out, am I doing something wrong or is this a marketplace error.

Comment: What's the name of your metadata file?

Comment: My file name is 1.json

Comment: That is the problem. The default `tokenURI()` function won't pick up the `.json` part. You would need to either upload your metadata without extensions, or change the `tokenURI()` to incorporate the `.json` part.

Comment: `return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString(), ".json")) : "";`

Something like this.